# Can't release file in asp.net MVC on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file, handle

Here's the function i made :

```
if (Valide())
{
    try
    {
        File.Delete(Server.MapPath("F16client.pdf"));
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    using (FileStream ms = new FileStream(Server.MapPath("F16client.pdf"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        PdfReader lecteur = new PdfReader(Server.MapPath("~/Formulaires/f16.pdf"));

        PdfStamper etampeur = new PdfStamper(lecteur, ms);

        // DO STUFF, Whatever

        etampeur.FormFlattening = true;
        etampeur.Close();
        lecteur.Close();

        System.Net.Mail.Attachment at = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("F16client.pdf"));                                            
    }
}
```

It work when testing local, but on IIS, this W3W process won't let go of my f16client.pdf and i always end up with :

> The process cannot access the file 'D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Formulaire16\F16client.pdf' because it is being used by another process.

Why is that file still in use when on IIS and not when testing local ??????

Comment: Do you have the file open elsewhere?

Comment: What happens if you move this line out of the using statement? System.Net.Mail.Attachment at = new Attachment(Server.MapPath("F16client.pdf"));

Comment: I would suggest creating Temp files instead -- there's a few problems with the code as you have it.

Comment: My guess would be that the server deletes asynchronously.    However, I am not sure about that.  So the server sends a delete request to the OS, which then returns control to your application.   Before the delete actual finishes, your program tries to create it, hence the error message

Comment: @FeryalBadili Hey, you'r right, the attachment is holding the file forever, i mean, until IIS decides to release it after hours of inactivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... no magic here. Thanks to Feryal Badili for pointing out the problem, an email attachement is something that actually holds the ressource...

So, a simple :

```
    at.Dispose();
```

before the end of the function and alls good. Yeah...

The reason why it worked on local is probably because i was pushing the `stop everything` button everytime i tested, and therefore, i was killing the handle everytime it tried my function.

Answer (score 0):

Check the access for the Application Pool user on IIS. Then try again with this code below:

```
var file = Server.MapPath("F16client.pdf")
File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);
File.Delete(file);
```

This can be a permission or file attribute problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i verified, usualy my web apps have 100% control on the files it own (and it's the case right now), but still a good practice to check the rights and attributs.